# the same background on the one side of container

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve effects like in this picture.

I do not know what CSS rules should I include to right side of container which has blue background and the left side has margin auto

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `div` with fixed `width` property and set `float:right`

```css
#blue-column{
  width:70vw;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#118ded;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue-column"></div>
```